# How to find rate in many to many relation if both foreign key match?

Tags: laravel

This is my User Item Pivot Table

```
| item_id | user_id | rate |
```

and i have defined many to many relation in both User and Item Model
This is my User Model

```
public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class, 'item_user')->withPivot('rate');
    }
```

This is my Item Model

```
 public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'item_user')->withPivot('rate');
    }
```

This is My Controller.Suppose I have item_id.I want to find rate of where user and item_id id match.

```
 public function findRate(Request $request){
        $user=User::where('id',auth()->user()->id)->first();
        $item_rate=$user->items->where('item_id', '1')->first();
        dd($user);
        return response()->json([
            'item_rate'=>$item_rate,
        ]);

    }
```

I tried like this but Error say Property [pivot] does not exist on this collection instance

```
  $item_rate=$user->items->where('item_id', '1')->pivot()->rate;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 $item_rate=$user->items()
            ->where('item_id',1)
            ->first()
            ->pivot
            ->rate;
```

Comment: Please don't post code only answer. Add some lines to describe your answer which will help  future reader to understand your solution.